# Talking between Flash and a TCP Server (Python)

Tags: python, flash, gevent

What is the best recommended way to talk between a Flash client and gevent? Should I use XMLSocket or is there something better... also, should I create my own syntax "such as MOVE 1, 500, 3000" or should I use something similar to JSON? This is for production, thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash has a serialisation format called AMF (ActionScript Message Format). I’ve found it to be faster than XML or JSON, and it’s also terser (i.e.: produces smaller payloads than XML or JSON). I’ve only used it for a couple of projects, but check out [amfast](http://code.google.com/p/amfast/) and [PyAMF](http://www.pyamf.org/) for the server-side. Both projects come with code examples for both the client- and server-side.

Another advantage of AMF is that it allows you to share "native" objects between Python and Flash, i.e. you can serialise a `datetime.datetime` at the Python end and get out an ActionScript `Date` when you deserialise it in Flash.